# golang SQL DB opens connections when there are idle ones

Tags: go

We are using https://github.com/dlmiddlecote/sqlstats to expose the connection metrics, setting `maxOpenConns` to `300`, and `maxIdleConns` to `220`. The metrics graph is

[image]

[image]

We can see there are a lot of idle connections in the first graph. But the server is also closing connections due to max idle connections reached. I believe this means that the `sql.DB` package is creating more connections than `maxIdleConn`, and later has to remove them. But, looking at the first graph, why does `sql.DB` need to create more connections and exceed `maxIidleConn` if there are a lot of idle connections around already?